# Get object from vector by value

Tags: c++, c++14

This seems like a dumb question, but I just want to verify it. If I want to get an object in a vector by value, I can use [], correct? If I want it by reference, I need to use myvector.at(), right? Is there a way to return an item by value? As an example:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos;
foos.push_back(Foo());
Foo f1 = foos[0]; // by value
Foo f2 = foos.at(0); // by reference
```

Comment: Both `v[i]` and `v.at(i)` return the item by reference.

Comment: @Eljay Thank you for that, is there any way to return an item by value?

Comment: BTW, the diff between [] and at is that at range checks but [] does not

Comment: `Foo foo = foos[0];` will take the return-by-reference and make it into a value.

Answer (score 2):

That's not correct. Both `vector::operator[]` and `vector::at` return references to the object at requested index. In case of `vector::at`, out of bound errors are implicitly checked and exception is raised. `vector::operator[]` is similar to an array access.